# How to modify dynamically a django widget parameter?

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have such a form :

```
class ChangeParentCIForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CINodeInventory
        fields = ('parent',)
        widgets = {'parent': AutocompleteWidget('inventory.uuid'),}
```

The problem is that, in my case, the AutocompleteWidget content must be contextual not only with the 'parent' field value, but also with a user session information (for me a database version number chosen by the user on another page)

To do so, I did something like this into the class-based view :

```
class CompanyManageChangeParentCIView(CompanySelectedMixin,CIContextMixin,CompanyViewCIMixin,UpdateView):    
    template_name = 'inventory/browse_change_parent_ci.html'
    context_object_name = 'ci'
    form_class = ChangeParentCIForm

    def get_form(self,form_class):
        form = super(CompanyManageChangeParentCIView,self).get_form(form_class)
        form.base_fields['parent'].widget.url_params={'version':self.request.session['use_version']}
        return form
```

Of course I modified AutocompleteWidget code to take care of this 'url_params' extra parameter.

It works, but this code does not seems to me very beautiful because it modifies widget created at init time for a field that is also generated at init time.
with anothers words, if you created 2 form instances, it points to the same fields and widgets, so if I do this :

```
def get_form(self,form_class):
    form1 = super(CompanyManageChangeParentCIView,self).get_form(form_class)
    form2 = super(CompanyManageChangeParentCIView,self).get_form(form_class)
    form1.base_fields['parent'].widget.url_params="val1"
    form2.base_fields['parent'].widget.url_params="val2"
    print id(form1),id(form1.base_fields['parent'].widget)
    print id(form2),id(form2.base_fields['parent'].widget)
```

One can see form1 and form2 are to different instances, but they point to the same widgets (and the same fields if print their id). So for me, if I display form1 and form2 into the same template, I will display 2 widgets "AutocompleteWidget", but both customized with the latest modification, that is url_parms="val2"

Even If I display one form, it seems to me very dangerous, what is happening if 2 threads are executing the same code with 2 different "url_params" values for a same widget ?

So here is my question : how to customize a django widget rendering with a contextual information and not only with its related field value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are changing `form.base_fields`, which is shared by all instances of the class. Don't do that, change `form.fields`, which is instance-specific.

As a matter of style, I'd prefer to do this in the `__init__` method of the form itself, and pass the URL param as a form kwarg - looks like you can override the view's `get_form_kwargs` method to do that, then you won't need to change `get_form` at all.